# how to send request to wcf webservices in PAN using bluetooth in android

Tags: android, android-webservice

i have a data service in PAN, Can it possible send request from mobile to server using bluetooth in Personal area network(PAN)..

Comment: Describe your problem briefly, what is this?

Comment: this is wcf web service? or rssfeed?

Comment: i have wcf web services in local system when i am trying to get response from that url it showing in like this..

Comment: `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname. HTTP Error 400 The request hostname is invalid`. Is your local web service accessible to external access?

Comment: This is OData services @Pankaj

Comment: @AndrewT. when i am tried in browser it showing proper response in XML

Comment: Show us the code on how you connect to your local web service in your Android app.

Comment: @AndrewT. android code updated in question can u check once

Comment: Have you tried using full address by adding the protocol `http`?

Comment: ya tried.. stackoverflow not accepting local address so edited like that and in browser if i use localhost in url its working properly when i use ip of system instead of localhost it showing invalid hostname

Comment: as my observevation whatever response coming on browser when i am using  ip same i getting in android also